# AddressOf not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, addhandler, addressof

I am having a issue with a c# to vb.net conversion, but `AddHandler` is not working for me. Can anyone help?

```
this.ucSurveyWebControl.OnResponseRecieved += new MentorLogic.Engines.Zodiac.Web.OnResponseRecieved(ucSurveyWebControl_OnResponseRecieved);
```

VB.net code: does not work

```
Me.ucSurveyWebControl.OnResponseRecieved += New MentorLogic.Engines.Zodiac.Web.OnResponseRecieved(ucSurveyWebControl_OnResponseRecieved)
```

`AddHandler` example but does not work

```
AddHandler MentorLogic.Engines.Zodiac.Web.OnResponseRecieved, AddressOf ucSurveyWebControl_OnResponseRecieved
```

error messages for `BC32008`: Delegate

```
'MentorLogic.Engines.Zodiac.Web.OnResponseRecieved' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

error `BC30676`: 'OnResponseRecieved' is not an event of 'MentorLogic.Engines.Zodiac.Web'. Page Validation Complete
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the concrete object instead of the class:

```
AddHandler Me.ucSurveyWebControl.OnResponseRecieved, AddressOf ucSurveyWebControl_OnResponseRecieved
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
AddHandler Me.ucSurveyWebControl.OnResponseRecieved, AddressOf ucSurveyWebControl_OnResponseRecieved
```